# Countable sum of continuous functionals.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a countable family of continuous functionals on a topological space $(X,\tau)$ such that $0\leq f_i \leq 1$. I want to show that $\sum_{i} \frac{f_i}{2^i}$ is continuous.

Can you think of a slick argument to show this?

Comment: How do you define $2^i$? Is $I$ a subset of $\Bbb \{0,1,\dots\}$?

Comment: $I$ is just a countable set, so yes, you can take it to be a subset of $\mathbb{N}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $I \subset \Bbb N$. Then the series is normally convergent since
$$
\sum_{i\in I} \sup_X \frac{|f_i|}{2^i} \leq \sum_{i \in I} \frac{1}{2^i} \leq 2
$$

Using the fact that $\Bbb R$ is complete, $g = \sum_{i\in I} \frac{f_i}{2^i}$ is the limit of a uniformly convergent sequence of $C(X,\Bbb R)$, hence is continuous.

---

**Elementary proof (by hand)**

Fix $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Let $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{i > N} \dfrac{1}{2^{i}} \leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{4}$. Since $f_1,\dots,f_N$ are continuous at $x$, there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $x$  such that
$$
\forall y \in V,\forall i\in\{1,\dots,N\}\cap I,\qquad |f_i(x) - f_i(y)| \leq \frac{\epsilon}{2}.
$$
With this choice, for every $y \in V$,
$$
|g(x) - g(y)| \leq \sum_{i \in I}_{i \leq N} \frac{|f_i(x)-f_i(y)|}{2^i} + \frac{\epsilon}{4}\times 1 + \frac{\epsilon}{4}\times 1 \leq \epsilon 
$$

We conclude that $g$ is continuous at $x$ for every $x \in X$.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I knew. It's just a tad messy in its formality.

Comment: Tell me if you prefer the new one.

Comment: Yes, very clever. nice one!